# Is it common to omit "about" when using the phrase **excited about** in spoken English?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

I assume these two sentences are grammatical and idiomatic.

"[Maria’s starting to get pretty excited **about** the wedding](https://www.ldoceonline.com/ko/dictionary/excited)."

"I'm excited **about** it."

It sounds like the speaker is [saying](https://youtu.be/zH2s4XSEWO0?t=701)

> It was the first AI boom. People were really **excited** it.

So, is it common to omit "about" when using the phrase **excited about** in spoken English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hear "People were really excited. It was the AI boom ... "

The speaker is clearly fluent in English, but he is equally clearly not a native speaker, so his accent may be misleading you at times.